# How to fix my scanner in error if my .txt file is empty?

Tags: java, file

I'm taking in strings from a file and places them into a LinkedList.  The program works fine when the .txt file has data in it.
However, when no data is in the .txt file it seems to throw an error...

```
    exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
    at task.main.main(main.java:85)
```

Would an if/else statement fix this??

here's the code I'm using, which works if the .txt file has data.

```
    //read in task data and place task data in a LL
            String contentComplete = new Scanner(new File("completeData.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            LineNumberReader  lnr4 = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("completeData.txt")));
            lnr4.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            lnr4.close();
            realSize = lnr4.getLineNumber();
            sizeOfIn = ((lnr4.getLineNumber() + 1) / 4); //divide by two because every 4 lines is equal to one input
            //-----TEST number of data entries
            System.out.println("Number of data entries from progressData.txt: " + sizeOfIn);
            //-----Number of lines
            System.out.println("Number of lines from progressData: " + realSize);
            //splits userData.txt input 2 parts
            String[] completeContent = contentComplete.split("\n");
            //loads taskData into a LL
            //update: changed i < sizeOfIn to i < realSize and it appears to be loading correctly

            for(int i = 0; i < realSize; i++) {
                task tempTask = new task(completeContent[i], completeContent[i+1], completeContent[i+2], completeContent[i+3]);
                completeLL.add(tempTask);
                i = i + 3;
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: What's the problem checking for an empty file/string first?

Answer (score 1):

You did not share all your code but considering the error message it seems you did not check if the scanner still had some tokens in its input before asking for the next token

for this purpose you should use `scanner.hasNext()` method:

> hasNext() 
>   Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

so do something like

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // Process here the input from the scanner
    // for example String data = scanner.next();
}
```

It could also be that you don't need to implement it in a loop but just with a if like:

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
   // Process here....
}
```